# JS: ObservableArray Filtering

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have one observableArray like below,

```
var details = ko.observableArray([]);
details = [
      { AccName: "Jane Doe", ExpDt: '2019-01-10', Contract: "Trial" },
      { AccName: "John", ExpDt: '2018-12-30', Contract:  "Licensed"},
      { AccName: "Doe", ExpDt: '2018-09-10', Contract:  "Trial"}
];
```

From this, I need to extract users based on ExpDt and Contract.

```
For Ex => ExpDt < today dt (2019-01-10) and having "trial" contract
Answer should be => Jane Doe
```

Please give me some suggestion on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

```js
const details=[{AccName:"Jane Doe",ExpDt:"2019-01-10",Contract:"Trial"},{AccName:"John",ExpDt:"2018-12-30",Contract:"Licensed"},{AccName:"Doe",ExpDt:"2018-09-10",Contract:"Trial"}];

const res = details.filter(({ExpDt, Contract})=>{
  const darr = ExpDt.split("-");
  //Date.UTC accepts months from 0 - 11
  darr[1] = darr[1] - 1;
  return Date.UTC(...darr) < Date.now() && Contract === "Trial";
})

console.log(res);
```

You get two results because Doe also fits the requirments:

```
ExpDt: 2018-09-10 < 2019-01-10
Contract: Trial === Trial
```